# I don't understand what's wrong in my implementation of cp command

Tags: c, unix, cp

I'm trying to simulate `cp` on UNIX using C. Here's my code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  int src, dest;
  char buff[256];
  int bits_read;

  src = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  dest = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0644);

  if (dest < 0)
    perror("Er");

  while ((bits_read = read(src, buff, sizeof(buff))) > 0)
    if (bits_read != write(dest, buff, sizeof(buff)))
      perror("Er");

  close(src);
  close(dest);

  return 0;
}
```

I'm getting the following output:

`Er: Undefined error: 0`

I can see that the new file contains some repeated lines at the end.

Comment: You never checked for the count of arguments!!

Comment: You should write only what has been read (thus replace `sizeof(buff)` by `bits_read`.

Comment: Shouldn't you have O_APPEND set?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I have neglected the exceptions, but I can assure you that I'm passing the correct arguments.

Comment: The last line is not sizeof(buf) long. Should you use `if (bits_read != write(dest, buff, bits_read))` ?

Comment: @mnistic No. I would like to erase all the contents of the file if it already exists.

Comment: @AProgrammer Thanks. That solved the problem. I now understand what was happening.

Comment: @WalterA That solved the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line is not sizeof(buf) long.
Use

```
if (bits_read != write(dest, buff, bits_read))
```

Comment: I just now see that @AProgrammer found the same explanation earlier than I did.He deserves credits!

Comment: As a small point it's not that the last _line_ in the file isn't `sizeof(buff)` bytes long — `read()` and `write()` aren't aware of line conventions — but that the last chunk read is smaller than size.